# Attract Traffic on my Honeypot

Tags: honeypot, threats

I have deployed a low-interaction honeypot on my ec2 aws instance but I am not receiving any traffic. Where can I share the URL so that I can get more traffic especially from automated bots.

Comment: How long has the honeypot online? What kind of service is exposed, SSH or other? Have you tested the honeypot yourself to make there are no firewall rules masking the existence of the service?

Comment: Depending on the services configured (type, known vulnerable) you may have to wait quite some time for mass scanners (Shodan, Censys, etc.) to hit your system as many actors leverage these services over building their own scanning infrastructure.

Comment: The honeypot has been up for a day but I got 0 traffic

Comment: I googled "how to get traffic to my honeypot" and the duplicate above was the top hit.

Answer (score -2):

Why do you *want* to attract malicious actors? I can assume research but context will dictate the best answer.

If you are running an application on AWS then the idea, in my experience, would be to have it behind the firewall. That way you can block outgoing traffic and it looks more legitimate to an adversary.

Edit: short, messy answer is social media that you believe would be scraped.